# How to use springEL to dynamically set the class type of a bean

Tags: spring

I am using MappingJacksonJsonView as the default view, but in spring4, we need to use MappingJackson2JsonView as the default view, I want to use springEL in the config xml to dynamically set the bean's class to MappingJacksonJsonView or MappingJackson2JsonView depending on the spring version we loaded, I tried with following, but not working.

```
<bean
            class="{T(org.springframework.core.SpringVersion).getVersion().split(\"\\.\")[0].compareTo("4")==0 ?
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView :
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView }" />
```